# Wildcard in python string

Tags: python, arrays, string, split, wildcard

I need to use the `.split()[]` to split a string. The issue I am having is that the section that needs to be split also needs to have a wildcard in it. Lets say the string is `Mr. Robot S03E04 eps3.3_m3tadata.par2` I would like to use `item.split("S??E??", 1)[0]`to be able to turn the string into `Mr. Robot S03E04` and then put it back into an array.

Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
import feedparser

URL = "http://followshows.com/feed/ZQU98gqv"

feed = feedparser.parse(URL)

for index in range(len(feed.entries)):
    item = feed.entries[index].title
    print item.split("S??E??", 1)[0]
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to look into regular expressions

Comment: use the following regex in case your S and E are always followed by 2 digits
S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]

For more information, please refer to the official documentation on the subject:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions would be useful here.

```
import re;  
re.split('e.t', 'This is a testing string');  
['This is a t', 'ing string']
```

The dot character in the regular expression is a wildcard for a single character.

To do what you have asked in your question:

```
re.split('S..E..', item)[0];
```

Note that this does not verify that the substring actually exists in the string. For that, use re.search.

Comment: Thank you. i tried reading the documentation but its very confusing to me. is there anyway to make the split after the substring?

Comment: To get the part of the string after the first occurrence of the substring (but before the second) would use [1] instead of [0]. re.split returns a list; you can choose the index.

Comment: i see what youre saying but i wish to keep the `S..E..` but nothing after

Comment: Correction - it would be [:2] for nothing after.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have managed to get it working with this

`trans1 = re.split('(S..E..)', item)[0]; trans2 = trans1.join(re.split('(S..E..)', item)[1:2]); trans3 = trans1 + trans2; print(trans3)`